# To select the data in another textbox based on dropdown list in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i have one form in which,i want to select organization name then automatically need to display hq no of that organization name in another textbox,whether both are in same table.

```
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="orgName">Org Name</label>

             <select class="form-control required" id="orgName"name="orgName"> <option value="0">
                    Select Orgnization</option>
      <?php if(!empty($orgNames)){  foreach ($orgNames as $pl){ ?><option value="<?php echo $pl->customerId ?>"><?php echo $pl->orgName ?></option><?php}?> </select>
       </div></div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                             <label for="hqNo">HQ No.</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form- control required" id="hqNo" name="hqNo" maxlength="128">
                                 </div>
```

Comment: You have to provide us with what you have done

Comment: Update the question with these html tags along with the javaScript scripts you've worked on till now please - otherwise none will be able to help you

Comment: You need to provide your code if you want anyone's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that option value are hqNo for that organization:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="orgName">Org Name</label>
    <select class="form-control required" id="orgName" name="orgName" onchange="onOrganizationChange()"> 
      <option value="0">Select Orgnization</option>
      <?php if(!empty($orgNames)) {  foreach ($orgNames as $pl){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $pl->customerId ?>"><?php echo $pl->orgName; ?></option>
      <?php } ?> 
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="hqNo">HQ No.</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="hqNo" name="hqNo" maxlength="128">
</div>

<script>
    function onOrganizationChange() {
        var orgVal = document.getElementById("orgName").value;
        document.getElementById('hqNo').value = orgVal;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please approve the answer so that others can get help from it in future